# Log in a site and navigate another pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have a script for Python 2 to login into a webpage and then move inside to reach a couple of files pointed to on the same site, but different pages. Python 2 let me open the site with my credentials and then create a `opener.open()` to keep the connection available to navigate to the other pages.

Here's the code that worked in Python 2:

```
$Your admin login and password
LOGIN = "*******"
PASSWORD = "********"
ROOT = "https:*********"

#The client have to take care of the cookies.
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))

#POST login query on '/login_handler' (post data are: 'login' and 'password').
req = urllib2.Request(ROOT + "/login_handler",
                      urllib.urlencode({'login': LOGIN,
                                        'password': PASSWORD}))
opener.open(rep)

#Set the right accountcode

for accountcode, queues in QUEUES.items():
    req = urllib2.Request(ROOT + "/switch_to" + accountcode)
    opener.open(req)
```

I need to do the same thing in Python 3. I have tried with request module and urllib, but although I can establish the first login, I don't know how to keep the opener to navigate the site. I found the OpenerDirector but it seems like I don't know how to do it, because I haven't reached my goal.

I have used this Python 3 code to get the result desired but unfortunately I can't get the csv file to print it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZscc.png)

Comment: Please show your python 3 code and the errors you get

Comment: Current Python 3 docs have good example of urllib opener & sample code that works, see: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib Section: Basic Authentication

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I don't know how to keep the opener to navigate the site.
>
> Python 3.6» Documentation [urllib.request.build_opener](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.build_opener)
>
> Use of Basic HTTP Authentication:
>
> ```
> import urllib.request
> # Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
> auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
> auth_handler.add_password(realm='PDQ Application',
>                       uri='https://mahler:8092/site-updates.py',
>                       user='klem',
>                       passwd='kadidd!ehopper')
>
> opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
>
> # ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
> urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
> f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/login.html')
> csv_content = f.read()
> ```

Comment: the problem for me is cause i have to use an user and password then after the log in keep on navigating the site (this is why the opener) and then download the files.

Comment: _**it didn't work**_  Doesn't help,  Check Response Error or Code you got. Have you verfied the Login was successful? **PLEASE** don't use `Answer` for your Comments, [edit] your Question accordingly. **PLEASE**don't use Pictures  [edit] your Question an add your current `Python3`.

Comment: May I see `print(f.status)` and  `print(f.reason)`. [Edit] your Question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use python requests library for python 3 and session.
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Once you login your session will be automatically managed. You dont need to create your own cookie jar. Following is the sample code.

```
s = requests.Session()
auth={"login":LOGIN,"pass":PASS}
url=ROOT+/login_handler
r=s.post(url, data=auth)
print(r.status_code)
for accountcode, queues in QUEUES.items():
    req = s.get(ROOT + "/switch_to" + accountcode)
    print(req.text) #response text
```

Comment: unfortunatelly it didnt work neither, I cant complete the required login before start to read.

Comment: Did you change the parameters appropriately?For username and password.

Comment: Yes I did but it looks like I can't complete the authentication for that. the password and user are ok cause each time that I'M try with my browser that works